# Keep getting tuple error when inserting into rds database

Tags: python, sql-server, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have a dataframe that I'm trying to loop through to insert data into a and rds database I get the following error returned from my aws-lambda function:

> [ERROR] AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'user_id'

My code is simple, I read a file in from s3 bucket, decode it, read it to memory and loop through each row.

```
mycsv = client.get_object(Bucket = aml_bucket, Key = file_name)
bc_body = mycsv['Body']
csv_string = bc_body.read().decode('utf-8')
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string))
for row in df.iterrows():
  cursor.execute('''insert into new_table(user_id, first_name)
  VALUES(?,?)'''
  row.user_id,
  row.first_name)
```

I've removed it from my s3 and ran it locally to print, it prints the value. I've started at the 6th row and it prints the value. The moment I try to insert it into a table it falls over in my lambda function. Please help

Comment: `iterrows()` returns a tuple `(row_index, row)`. Split it during iteration `for index, row in df.iterrows():`

Comment: Do I have to call index in the for loop?

Comment: You don't need to use the `index`, just unpack it. Currently `row` is actually `(row_index, actual_row)` so `index, row = (row_index, actual_row)`

Comment: I don't understand, would you mind showing me an example?

Comment: oh so like `for row in iterrows(0,1):`

Comment: When I iterate through it I get this error `[ERROR] TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not list`

Comment: replace `for row in df.iterrows()` with `for index, row in df.iterrows():`. Change nothing else..

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly indicates the issue in your code, you have to update the code like

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  cursor.execute('''insert into new_table(user_id, first_name)
  VALUES(?,?)'''
  row['user_id'],
  row['first_name'])
```

assuming the DF is defined to have user_id and first_name